# Add specifications table for products page

Tags: custom-post-types

I have a WordPress issue that has been keeping me busy for a few days.

I'm currently building a website for a client.

This website will show products and each product page also has a table with specifications of the product.

The specifications will be shown in a table like this:

[image: http://preview.navinpoeran.com/images/tabel.jpg]

What would be the best way to implement this in the template, so the client can add data for each product from the back-end?

Each product gets its own page of course.

For example:

iPhone 4S
iPhone 5
etc. (no it's not an Apple-related website, just an example)

Answer (score 2):

You could easily do that with [Product Specifications](https://wordpress.org/plugins/product-specifications/) plugin.
This plugin is built for this purpose and you won't need any additional code, However it comes with a `[specs-table]` shortcode that you can use elsewhere.

The plugin automatically adds a tab called "product specifications" to woocommerce single product page and shows product spec. table, 
Read more at [plugin's page](https://wordpress.org/plugins/product-specifications/) on wordpress.org

Comment: This is a very old question, so only reason to answer it now is to inform the future visitors. Please don't just link a plugin, explain a little on how you may use it to answer the question, link to documentation etc. Also, mention if it is your own plugin. Otherwise it looks like a spam.

Comment: This plugin is built for this purpose , and it doesn't need any additional code, it will add a new tab to woocommerce product page and shows a table however you could customize the table with CSS.

Comment: Yes, I was talking about that. The comment you've added now, that description should be part of your answer. That way everyone will have a clear idea on what it is before even visiting the link. StackExchange sites have specific recommendation on how to answer. Please read this: http://meta.wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/1251/110572

Comment: Great! +1 for the added description.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this by adding Meta Boxes to your custom post type. Here's two URLs that explain it, it's pretty easy:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_meta_box
http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/integrating-with-wordpress-ui-meta-boxes-on-custom-pages/

The Meta Box just works like another field to edit on the Post edit screen so integrates really well. You should be able to layout a grid like you specified above.

You can use [update_post_meta()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_post_meta) to save your values to the database so no extra DB tables or fields are required.

Answer (score 0):

Steve's answer above is the best way of doing it, of course, but if the client isn't too afraid of technology, she could also just add the required data via the standard custom field interface. Not quite as user-friendly, though.
There's also the [Advanced Custom Fields](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/) plugin, if you don't fancy rolling your own metaboxes.